# Making C++ run at full speed

Tags: c++, processor

To compare C++ and Java on certain tasks I have made two similar programs, one in Java and one in C++. When I run the Java one it takes 25% CPU without fluctuation, which you would expect as I'm using a quad core. However, the C++ version only uses about 8% and fluctuates havily. I run both programs on the same computer, on the same OS, with the same programs active in the background. How do I make C++ use one full core? These are 2 programs both not interrupted by anything. They both ask for some info and then enter an infinite loop until you exit the program, giving feedback on how many calculations per second.

The code:

http://pastebin.com/5rNuR9wA

http://pastebin.com/gzSwgBC1

http://pastebin.com/60wpcqtn

To answer some questions:

I'm basically looping a bunch of code and seeing how often per second it loops. The problem is: it doesn't use all the CPU it can use. The whole point is to have the same processor do the same task in Java and C++ and compare the amount of loops per second. But if one is using irregular amounts of CPU time and the other one is looping stable at a certain percentage they are hard to compare. By the way, if I ask it to execute this:

```
while(true){}
```

it takes 25%, why doesn't it do that with my code?

----edit:----

After some experimenting it seems that my code starts to use less than 25% if I use a cout statement. It isn't clear to me why a cout would cause the program to use less cpu (I guess it pauses until the statement is written which appearantly takes a while?

With this knowledge I will reprogram both programs (to keep them comparable) and just let it report the results after 60 seconds instead of every time it completed a loop.

Thanks for all the help, some of the tips were really helpful. After I discovered the answer someone also turned out to give this as an answer, so even if I wouldn't have found it myself I would have gotten the answer. Thanks!

(though I would like to know why a std::cout takes such an amount of time)

Comment: Depends entirely what it is doing. It may be spending that time waiting for... something. Memory, disk, i/o, I dunno.

Comment: Without seeing code, impossible.  Your C++ program is either less efficient or compiled without optimizations or something else.

Comment: I could post the code if you think that's useful, but shouldn't less efficiency mean it just does less with the cpu usage it has?

Comment: you can't compare the cpu usage from java and c++ they are just not the same, java does a lot of other things in the background. Probably your code is not optimized or you are calling some functions that sleep the thread

Comment: @Joe surely if the C++ does the same thing with less CPU, it's *more* efficient ;-)

Comment: @RogerRowland ...at the same speed ;)

Comment: The ammount of CPU a piece of code uses != efficiency. I can easily achieve a full core usage with a `while(true){i++}` loop, but if that doesn't really do anything I'm just wasting cycles. In the case of Java, a ton of that CPU time may be running on JIT Compiling, or maintaining the JVM, all of which may be less efficient than your code.

Comment: How are you measuring CPU usage? and what 'task' in the program do you want to be running in the least amount of time? I assume you want the CPU to be fully loaded to minimize the time the program 'task' is running.

Comment: So your C++ code uses only 1/3 of the CPU time your Java code uses while it is not blocked in system calls, in other words runs 3 times more efficiently than your Java code. What exactly don't you like about that? :)  Worded differently, **every** kind of language uses 100% CPU while there is something to do (i.e. when you're not waiting for input or for disk access or sleeping). If your C++ program performs an equivalent task with 1/3 the CPU load, that's mighty fine.

Comment: @Damon It's not doing the same with less CPU. It's doing less with less CPU. I would like them to be 100% comparable but it's undoable when one fluctuates havily

Comment: Suggestion: use vector calculations instead of trigonometry. It's both simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Measuring performance with something that contains `cout`? At the very least, set `cout.sync_with_stdio(false);`.

Comment: Try replacing `if (time(&timer) - startTime>0)` with `if(0)`? See what the CPU load is then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main loop has a `cout` in it, which will call out to the OS to write the accumulated output at some point. Either OS time is not counted against your app, or it causes some disk IO or other activity that forces your program to wait.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not accurate to compare both of these running at the same time without considering the fact that they will compete for cpu time. The OS will automatically choose the scheduling for these two tasks which can be affected by which one started first and a multitude of other criteria.

Running them both at the same time would require some type of configuration of the scheduling so that each one is confined to run to one (or two) cpus and each application uses *different* cpus. This can be done by having each main function execute a separate thread that performs all the work and then setting the cpu where this thread will run. In c++11 this can be done using a [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and then setting the underlying cpu affinity by getting the [native_handle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) and setting it there.

I'm not sure how to do this in Java but I'm sure the process is similar.

Comment: I'm not running them at the same time. I run one, then the other

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your post. Don't mind me. :)